# ¿Cómo hacer que un punto dibujado se mueva de coordenadas? - C# Windows Forms (Objeto dinámico)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que el usuario elije un destino al que quiere llegar dentro de un edificio y como respuesta se muestra un vídeo con el camino a seguir. A su vez, se representa sobre los planos del edificio un **punto localizador**, que **se va moviendo conforme avanza el vídeo**.

Para ello, **necesito saber cómo hacer que se mueva de unas coordenadas del plano a otras**. Imagino que será definiendo los puntos en los que el vídeo cambia de dirección y decirle que se mueva con la misma velocidad que el vídeo, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Aclarar que lo que se reproduce es, en realidad, una lista de reproducción compuesta por varios vídeos, los cuales crean un vídeo continuo hasta el destino elegido, ya que donde termina uno empieza el siguiente.

Hay que tener en cuenta que el usuario puede manejar el vídeo con controles como *pause, acelerar, rebobinar, play, avanzar la posición 10 segundos para adelante y para atrás*, por lo que el punto también deberá obedecer a esas órdenes.

De momento os muestro el código que he desarrollado para situar la imagen del plano y el punto dibujado.

```
    Graphics Grafico;
    Pen Lapiz = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);

//Planos es el nombre de la pictureBox donde se encuentra el plano del edificio
    private void Planos_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Grafico = e.Graphics;
        Grafico.DrawEllipse(Lapiz, Grafico.ClipBounds.Left + 174, Grafico.ClipBounds.Top + 123, 3, 3);
    }
```

No tengo muchos conocimientos de programación y estaría muy agradecida si me pudierais ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Deberás jugar con la localización del punto gráfico, puedes acceder a ella a través de

```
 Grafico.location = new point(x, y)
```

Si lo que quieres es acceder a la localización a través del ratón deberás usar un evento mouseMove o mouse click junto con la propiedad

```
  Grafico.location = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
```

Está propiedad te representa la posición del cursor en coordenadas de la pantalla y te movería el gráfico a la posición del ratón

Comment: Lo que pretendo es marcar de alguna manera las coordenadas por donde tiene que ir pasando el punto y cuando se reproduzca el vídeo, que **el punto se vaya moviendo con él por el camino que yo le he indicado**. **Teniendo en cuenta si el vídeo se pausa, acelera, se rebobina**... (PD: gracias por responder) @mourazo

Comment: Pero como quieres indicarle el camino? A lo mejor deberías buscar información acerca de una librería tipo Aforge para el procesamiento de movimientos y reconocimiento en los videos y luego valorar como implementarla en tu video. Nada!                   http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

Comment: Lo que he pensado que puede funcionar, sería marcar de alguna manera los puntos del plano por los que debe ir pasando el punto localizador y relacionar la velocidad de este con la del vídeo que se está reproduciendo. Por ejemplo, indicar al punto localizador que se mueva de unas coordenadas a otras a la misma velocidad a la que se mueve el vídeo. 

Yo estoy trabajando en la interfaz de Windows Forms, y por lo que he podido ver a primera vista, parece que Aforge es una infraestructura para crear algo más complejo.

Comment: Entonces deberás ir trabajando con gráfico.location e ir cambiándola mediante algún timer el cual tenga el tiempo  sincronizado con la velocidad de reproducción del video

Comment: Grafico.location por desgracia parece no existir. A lo mejor debería hacerlo con una imagen, es decir, insertar una imagen de un punto rojo en la imagen del plano. Y de alguna manera (la tengo que descubrir aun) ir diciéndole que se mueva con un timer